# Proving the limit of a product of functions is equal to the product of the limits

Tags: real-analysis

Given $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \ell$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = m$. Prove that $$\lim_{x\to a} fg(x) = \ell m$$

So we want to prove that given some $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a $\delta>0$ such that $$|fg(x) - \ell m|<\varepsilon \text{ when } |x-a|<\delta.$$

Now we shall note the following:

\begin{align}
|fg(x)-\ell m| &= |f(x)g(x)-\ell m| \\
&= |f(x)g(x) + \ell g(x) - \ell g(x) - \ell m| \\
&= |g(x)(f(x)-\ell) + \ell(g(x)-m)| \\
&\le |g(x)(f(x)-\ell)|+|\ell(g(x)-m)| \\
&= |g(x)||f(x)-\ell|+|\ell||g(x)-m| \\
&< |g(x)|\varepsilon + |\ell|\varepsilon \\
&= \varepsilon(|\ell|+|g(x)|) \\
&= \varepsilon(|\ell| + |g(x)+m-m|) \\
&\le \varepsilon(|\ell| + |g(x) - m| + |m|) \\
&< \varepsilon(|\ell| + |m| + \varepsilon)
\end{align}

But I am not really sure what to do next. Any tips?

Comment: Notice that $|g(x)|=|g(x)-m+m|\leq|g(x)-m|+|m|<\epsilon+|m|$.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Although, given this information I am still not sure how to proceed. I am left at the point $$|fg(x) - \ell m| < \varepsilon(|\ell| + |m| + \varepsilon)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a $\epsilon >0$

You know that $lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=l$, so take a $\epsilon_1 >0$ and you can write:

$\exists \delta_1>0: \forall x \in ]a-\delta_1,a+\delta_2[, |f(x)-l|<\epsilon_1$

Idem for g, if $M=max_{x\in [a-\delta_1/2,a+\delta_1/2]} {|f(x)|}$ (you can easily prove that it exists thanks to what's above and the compacts propreties) choose $\epsilon_2=\frac{\epsilon-\epsilon_1 |m|}{M}$

$\exists \delta_2 >0 : \forall x \in ]a-\delta_2,a+\delta_2[, |g(x)-m|<\epsilon_2$

Now you take $\delta = min(\delta_1/2,\delta_2/2)$ and $x \in ]a-\delta, a+\delta[$

$|f(x)g(x)-ml| = |(f(x)(g(x)-m) -m(f(x)-l)| \\
 \leq |f(x)| \epsilon_2 + |m|\epsilon_1\\ \leq M \frac{\epsilon-\epsilon_1|m|}{M} +|m|\epsilon_1 =\epsilon$

So you're errors were to use the same $\epsilon$. With what you know, you should construct on draft paper the inequalities and then choose the $\epsilon$ that help you.

Comment: I made a little mistake: you should take a $\epsilon_1$ such that $\epsilon-\epsilon_1|m| > 0$